# Просмотр случайной строки из sqlite в Android-приложении

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Есть SQLite бд с 10 тысячами строк.
В данных только id и text.

Как разумнее будет организовать вывод рандомной строки?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Так я делал в PHP, но тут же другой язык.

Comment: Антон, это не PHP, а SQL